# How can I print a modified asterisk triangle pattern using recursion?

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm using C++ and I've been tasked with using recursion to print a triangle with a certain pattern:

For example, if the user enters the integer 4, the console should output the following:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gf46V.jpg

Edit: And if the user enters the integer 3, the console should output the following:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Sqxb.jpg
This is all the information I have on the pattern.

So, I recognize that the pattern of stars on each line is:
1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 4 (max), 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1

But the furthest I've gotten using recursion is to print triangles of size n:

```
void starprint(int n) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        if (i == 1) std::cout << "*" << std::endl;
        else
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
            {
                std::cout << "*";
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
        if (i == n) 
            starprint(n - 1);
    }
}
```

So now I'm stuck, because the pattern is a bit strange and because my instinct for these things would be to use iteration instead of recursion and I'm a bit of a noob at recursion.

Any suggestions on how to approach this would be really helpful. Thanks guys!

Comment: The pattern is not clear. For example, what would the answer be for n = 1, n =2, n = 3 and n = 5?

Comment: All questions here must include all relevant information ***in the question itself as plain text***. This question must be [edit]ed, and the strange link replaced with the relevant information.

Comment: I think I understood the pattern, but feel free to add examples if you want.

Comment: @Daniel, I added another example of the pattern, those two are the only examples I have for this assignment.

Comment: The biggest value acts as a mirror for both sides. It gets easier thinking this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://cpp.sh/7ph43) you have an elegant recursive solution for this sequence:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;    

void printstar(int n){
    if(n == 1) {cout<<"1 "; return;}
    printstar(n - 1);
    cout<<n<<" ";
    printstar(n - 1);
}

int main() {
  printstar(4);
}

//output: 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 2 1 3 1 2 1
```

As I said in the comments, the way is to think that `n` will act as a mirror for both sides. Each side will be another isolated sequence which its middle will be `n - 1` (which will act as a mirror again), and so on.

```
 1   2  1  3  1 2 1 [4] 1 2 1 3 1 2 1

 1   2  1 [3] 1 2 1

 1  [2] 1

[1]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This made me realize I was totally approaching this incorrectly and now I understand it. It was a lot more elegant than my original code, thank you Daniel!